# Модификация string в postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Атрибут fio хранит 'Иванов Иван Михайлович'.

Мне нужно преобразовать в 'Иванов И. М.'

У меня получилось только сделать 'Иванов И.' вот так:

```
substr(fio, 1, strpos(fio,' ')-1)|| ' ' || substr(fio,strpos(fio,' ')+1,1)||'.' as fio
```

Получить 'М.' я не могу. Загвоздка в том, что, при использовании такой же логики, второй пробел обработать не получается (подходящей регулярки не нашел). Может, кто-то с этим сталкивался? Буду благодарен за ваши идеи и предложения.

`substr(string, from [, count])` - извлекает подстроку.

`strpos(string, substring)` - возвращает положение указанной подстроки.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться функцией замены по [регулярному выражению](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F):

```
regexp_replace(fio,'(\w+)\s+(.)\w*\s+(.)\w*','\1 \2. \3.')
```

[Тест на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/15004)

Answer (score 0):

```
split_part(fio, ' ', 1)||' '||substr(split_part(fio, ' ', 2), 1, 1)||'.'||substr(split_part(fio, ' ', 3), 1, 1)||'.'
```

`split_part(string text, delimiter text, field int)` - Разделяет строку string по символу delimiter и возвращает элемент по заданному номеру (считая с 1).